# android magento customer login(authentication) using using SOAP API

Tags: android, magento, soap

i facing problem while i try to login(authentication) magento customer. i cant find proper way for login customer using there email and password. so, can u suggest me that how can i make authentication or login customer in magento store using SOAP API.
       i tried this code as given bellow

```
env.dotNet = false;
            env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");

            request.addProperty("username", "xyz");
            request.addProperty("apiKey", "xyz");

            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
            Object result = env.getResponse();

            Log.d("sessionId", result.toString());

            // making call to get list of customers

            String sessionId = result.toString();
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerInfo");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
            request.addProperty("customerId", "2032");
            request.addProperty("email", "abc@def.com");
            request.addProperty("password", "password");


            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, env);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            result = env.getResponse();

            Log.d("Customer List", result.toString());
```

}

but it does not help me so is there any one who's have solution of my question.

Thank you....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct option for login the customer to magento.The password you retrieve from API is hash_password and you cant check the equality of password. But you can use the method explained below to login into magento.

1. Create an external php file and access the magento login there

   require_once('../magentosite/app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento 
   umask(0);
   Mage::app();

   $id = 1;

   try{
       $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($id)->authenticate($email, $password);
   }catch( Exception $e ){
       $result = false;
   }
2. Send the username and password from android to that php page using JSON,and get the "result".
3. if the result is "true" the username and password exist in the DB.

Comment: yes, you are right. i am using that json method but i want to use SOAP method if is it possible.. thanks @Remees

Comment: @Sameer Donga: Till my knowledge there is not.Do you know how to connect with magento REST from Android. If you know plz answer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074424/android-rest-client-for-magento

Comment: @Remees- no... i do not have any idea for your question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can check/login user using SOAP, you just need to extend it a little bit. At app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php add new function

```
public function login($email, $password){
        /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);
        try
        {
            $session->login( $email, $password );
            $customer = $session->getCustomer();

            return json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'userData' => $this->info($customer->getId())));
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

At app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/api.xml

```
<config>
<api>
    <resources>
        <customer translate="title" module="customer">
         <methods>
        ...
               <login translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>Login customer</title>
                    <acl>customer/login</acl>
                </login>
```

also at the end

```
        <acl>
        <resources>
            <customer translate="title" module="customer">
            ...
            <login translate="title" module="customer">
                    <title>Login</title>
            </login>
```

And here you can test yout login function

```
<?php
$host = "http://youmagentohost/index.php";
$client = new SoapClient($host."/api/soap/?wsdl"); //soap handle
$apiuser= "apiuser"; //webservice user login
$apikey = "apikey"; //webservice user pass
$action = "customer.login";
try {

    $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey);
    $params = array('email'=>'email@email.com', 'password'=>'password');

    print_r($client->call($sess_id, $action, $params));
}
catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
    echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
?>
```

Its not nice solution but its better than nothing. Don't forget to rewrite all core files ;)

Comment: "$client->call($sess_id, $action, $params);"This is a SOAP v1 call.How can I implement it in V2 of SOAP?

Comment: try $client->customerCustomerLogin($sess_id)

Comment: @kipas I think that code won't work because apiversion2 has not been even touched.The changes are done in v1api only.

Comment: You can find information about how to extend V2 API here http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-api-v2/ and it should work then ;)

Comment: How to test it from an android app?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can check/login user using SOAP
At app/code/core/local/Envato/Masterapi/etc/api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>

    <resources>

      <masterapi_loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/loginmodel_api</model>
        <title>Demo Custommoduleapi API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/loginmodel</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <customerlogin translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of masterapi</title>
          </customerlogin>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_loginmodel>




    </resources>


    <resources_alias>
      <loginmodel>masterapi_loginmodel</loginmodel>

    </resources_alias>

    <v2>
      <resources_function_prefix>
         <loginmodel>masterapiLoginmodel</loginmodel>

      </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>

    <acl>
      <resources>
        <masterapi translate="title" module="masterapi">
          <title>Loginmodel</title>
          <sort_order>5</sort_order>
          <loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </loginmodel>


        </masterapi>

      </resources>
    </acl>
  </api>
</config>
```

At app/code/core/local/Envato/Masterapi/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Mycustom_Masterapi>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </Mycustom_Masterapi>
      </modules>
      <global>
        <models>
          <masterapi>
            <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Model</class>
          </masterapi>
        </models>
        <helpers>
          <masterapi>
            <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Helper</class>
          </masterapi>
        </helpers>
      </global>
    </config>
```

At app/code/core/local/Envato/Masterapi/etc/wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">

  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <complexType name="fieldInfo">
        <sequence>
          <element name="entity_id" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="fieldInfoArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:fieldInfo[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>




    </schema>
  </types>

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="user" type="xsd:string" />
     <part name="pass" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListResponse">
    <part name="customlogin" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>



  <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListRequest" />
      <output message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListResponse" />
    </operation>



  </portType>





  <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>



  </binding>



  <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
      <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

At app/code/local/Mycustom/Masterapi/Model/Loginmodel/Api.php

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Mycustom/Masterapi/Model/Loginmodel/Api.php
class Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api 
{
  public function customerlogin($user,$pass)
  {

  /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);
        try
        {
            $session->login( $user, $pass);
            $customer = $session->getCustomer();

            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'valid', 'userData' => $customer->getId()));
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'userData' => $e->getMessage()));
        }



  }
}
```

At /app/code/local/Mycustom/Masterapi/Model/Loginmodel/Api/V2.php

```
<?php
//app/code/local/Envato/Customapimodule/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
class Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api_V2 extends Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api
{
}
```

IN android side :
call soap request :

```
      properties.put("sessionId", sessionId);
                properties.put("user", "qbc@fgfg.com"); 
                properties.put("pass","pass");
           request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin");
 env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to login as a customer is:

1. fetch email id of all customer
2. match it with entered email id
3. if it match, fetch hash password
4. split the hash password with ":"
5. encrypt the entered password with md5 method. MD5 method requires to string, one is "salt"(that is string in hash password after ":") and other entered password.
6. match the output of MD5 and the hash password (value before ":" )

Here is the code:

```
email = "xyz.@gmail.com";
string_password = "xyz@123";
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerCustomerList");
request.addProperty("sessionId",sessionId );            
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
androidHttpTransport.call("urn:Magento/customerCustomerList", env);
SoapObject response =  (SoapObject) env.getResponse();      

for(int i=1;i<lengthofResponse;i++)
{                         

   SoapObject  CustomerList = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);                        
   Object email_id=CustomerList.getProperty(6);
   int CustomerList_length = CustomerList.getPropertyCount();
   Object password=CustomerList.getProperty((CustomerList_length));
   selected_email_ids.add(email_id.toString());
   response_password=(password.toString().split(":"));
   selected_password.add(response_password[0]);     
   selected_salt.add(response_password[1]);     
   //comparing password                  
   if(email.equals(selected_email_ids.get(j)))
   {
        System.out.println("Email is currect");
        hash = md5( response_password[1] + string_password);
        if(hash.equals(selected_password.get(j)))
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        }
    }                                                   
}
```

Comment: This is the reason why I hate magento api... I have never seen such worstiest api in my life...